# ArangoDB bindVars with dot?

Tags: arangodb

I would like to sort ArangoDB query results by various properties of a nested object however the bound vars seem not to work with dots in the names so

```
query: FOR a IN collection SORT @key ASC RETURN a
bindVars: @key = 'a.b.c.d'
(or)      @key = 'a.x.y'
```

does not work

Is there a way how to "eval" the bound string to the nested property?

EDIT:
I found in the docs that
"key": [ "a", "b", "c" ] should work but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document reference (here: `a`) needs to remain in the query. It must not be part of the bind variable.

```
FOR a IN collection SORT a.@key ASC RETURN a

{ "key": ["b", "c", "d"] }
```

If you want to sort by two attributes:

```
FOR a IN collection SORT a.@key1 ASC, a.@key2 DESC RETURN a

{ "key1": ["b", "c", "d"], "key2": ["x", "y"] }
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! So I assume if I want to do a join and sort on either of the tables I need to put them in some output object.

E.g.

FOR a in coll1
FOR b in coll2
FILTER a.bID = b.ID
SORT @dynamicBind
RETURN MERGE({a, b})

is impossible so I have to
LET OUT = { a: a, b: b}
SORT out.@dynamicBind

Right?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to sort by an attribute of `a` or `b` dynamically using a single query with different bind parameters, then you need an intermediate object `out` and use e.g. `{ "dynamicBind": ["a","x","y"] }` as bind parameter (including `a` or `b`). You can also make the sort order a bind parameter , but how many attributes to sort by needs to be hard-coded in the query.